# Wifi Adapter was not recognizing

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have recently switched over to ubuntu. Previously on windows i am using a cheap wifi adapter and currently i am switched over to a ubuntu and the adapter wasn't recognizing by ubuntu. The retailer was provided the driver on cd after running those file i the wifi status still remains same. After long research i found my driver model name is rtl8188EUS also installed that driver that can also not worked me. The name of my driver is A-Tech 802.11n driver:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPRUE.jpg)

But while running the lsusb command on the terminal i am able to find my driver name as:[wireless]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter

Comment: What kernel are you using, check in terminal `uname -r`